# How to avoid duplicating objects with foreach

Tags: r, parallel-processing, mpi

I have a very huge string vector and would like to do a parallel computing using `foreach` and `dosnow` package. I noticed that `foreach` would make copies of the vector for each process, thus exhaust system memory quickly. I tried to break the vector into smaller pieces in a list object, but still do not see any memory usage reduction. Does anyone have thoughts on this? Below are some demo code:

```
library(foreach)
library(doSNOW)
library(snow)

x<-rep('some string', 200000000)
# split x into smaller pieces in a list object
splits<-getsplits(x, mode='bysize', size=1000000) 
tt<-vector('list', length(splits$start))  
for (i in 1:length(tt)) tt[[i]]<-x[splits$start[i]: splits$end[i]]

ret<-foreach(i = 1:length(splits$start), .export=c('somefun'), .combine=c)   %dopar% somefun(tt[[i]])
```

Comment: Just an idea: Do you see a drop in memory consumption when calling
`ret<-foreach( k in tt, .export=c('somefun'), .combine=c) %dopar% somefun(k)` ?

Comment: Thanks for the hint, Beasterfield, but it seems that `foreach` fails to recognize the `in` syntax.

Comment: I'm sorry, of course I meant `foreach( k = tt, ... )`.

Comment: It works! I also tried the `iterators` package, both the `iter` for list object and `isplit` for vector object avoid duplicating large vector into each process.

Answer (score 7):

The style of iterating that you're using generally works well with the `doMC` backend because the workers can effectively share `tt` by the magic of `fork`.  But with `doSNOW`, `tt` will be auto-exported to the workers, using lots of memory even though they only actually need a fraction of it.  The suggestion made by @Beasterfield to iterate directly over `tt` resolves that issue, but it's possible to be even more memory efficient through the use of iterators and an appropriate parallel backend.

In cases like this, I use the `isplitVector` function from the `itertools` package.  It splits a vector into a sequence of sub-vectors, allowing them to be processed in parallel without losing the benefits of vectorization.  Unfortunately, with `doSNOW`, it will put these sub-vectors into a list in order to call the `clusterApplyLB` function in `snow` since `clusterApplyLB` doesn't support iterators.  However, the `doMPI` and `doRedis` backends will not do that.  They will send the sub-vectors to the workers right from the iterator, using almost half as much memory.

Here's a complete example using `doMPI`:

```
suppressMessages(library(doMPI))
library(itertools)
cl <- startMPIcluster()
registerDoMPI(cl)
n <- 20000000
chunkSize <- 1000000
x <- rep('some string', n)
somefun <- function(s) toupper(s)
ret <- foreach(s=isplitVector(x, chunkSize=chunkSize), .combine='c') %dopar% {
  somefun(s)
}
print(length(ret))
closeCluster(cl)
mpi.quit()
```

When I run this on my MacBook Pro with 4 GB of memory

```
$ time mpirun -n 5 R --slave -f split.R
```

it takes about 16 seconds.

You have to be careful with the number of workers that you create on the same machine, although decreasing the value of `chunkSize` may allow you to start more.

You can decrease your memory usage even more if you're able to use an iterator that doesn't require all of the strings to be in memory at the same time.  For example, if the strings are in a file named 'strings.txt', you can use `s=ireadLines('strings.txt', n=chunkSize)`.

Comment: Especially with respect to `ireadLines`, this follows a manager / worker paradigm where the workers are spawned by a single manager process; is there a way to use `itertools` but in a a more SPMD fashion ([pbdR](https://rdav.nics.tennessee.edu/2012/09/pbdr/)-like), so that the management of R workers is left to mpirun? Putting the responsibility of process management entirely in the hands of mpirun seems like a better division of responsibilities.

Comment: @MartinMorgan: That's an interesting idea.  I've played around with my own SPMD-style package built on `Rmpi`, but I didn't think about using iterators in that context, although I have been interested in the idea of distributed iterators in other contexts.  I've never used `pbdR`, but I should check it out.